# using PVectors to make speed constant

Tags: java, processing, game-physics

I'm working on a school project in Processing, and I'm running into a bit of a problem. I have a `bulletList` array to that's looped in my `draw()` class, with `Bullet` objects that are initialized when the spacebar is pressed.

```
if(key==' '){
float currentPlayerX=playerX;
float currentPlayerY=playerY;
float currentMouseX=mouseX;
float currentMouseY=mouseY;
bullets.add(new 
Bullet(currentPlayerX,currentPlayerY,currentMouseX,currentMouseY));
}

//in the draw method()
for(Bullet b: bullets){
b.shoot();
}

class Bullet{
float bulletX;
float bulletY;
float rise;
float run;

Bullet(float pX, float pY,float mX,float mY){ 

//I get the slope from the mouse position when the bullet was instantiated 
to the bullet position (which starts at the player position and is
incremented out by the slope as shoot() is called

rise=(mY-pY)/12;
run=(mX-pX)/12;
bulletX=pX;
bulletY=pY;
}

void shoot(){

fill(255,0,0);
rect(bulletX,bulletY,7,7);
bulletX+=run;
bulletY+=rise;
}
}
```

Essentially, the trajectory of the `Bullet` is determined when the `bullet` object is first created, the end goal being: move the mouse to the desired direction, press the space bar, and watch the bullet go. The problem is the velocity is never constant. When the mouse is far away from the `Player` object, the speed is fine, but as the `rise` and `run` gets smaller as the mouse moves closer, the `Bullet` speed becomes really small. I actually ended up messing around with the `rise` and `run` floats, and dividing them by 12, because at their initial value the `Bullet` wasn't visible.

I've heard the `PVectors` are a good way to have velocity in games, but we never covered them in my class and I don't really know where to start. I've also tried dividing & multiplying by a constant to try to get a constant speed, but I'm basically shooting in the dark here. Any help is much appreciated, and please ask if you have any questions about how my code works; I'm happy to clarify.

Comment: Are you familiar with the mechanics of projectile motion?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is some basic trigonometry. Basically I'd [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program):

**Step one:** Get the angle between the source of the bullet and the mouse. Google "get angle between two points" for a ton of resources.

**Step two:** Convert the angle to a **unit vector** which is an x/y pair that you can think of as a heading. Google "convert angle to unit vector" for a ton of resources.

**Step three:** Multiply those x and y values of that unit vector by some speed to get the amount you should move the bullet each frame.

The `PVector` class does offer some of this functionality. Check out [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) for a list of useful functions.

If you're still stuck, please narrow your problem down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This can be as simple as one circle that follows the mouse. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much! It took me longer than I'd like to admit, but I finally got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kevin's answer I'd like to point you to a few helpful online resources:

- [Vector magnitude & normalization on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-natural-simulations/programming-vectors/a/vector-magnitude-normalization)
- [Daniel Shiffman's Nature of Code chapter on Vectors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWJkvxQXIa8&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZwSmtE13iJBcoI-r4y7iEc)

These should help you normalize then scale the vector to a set speed, wether you choose to use PVector or not.